# If else in "["; what to return

Tags: r

From a `data.frame`, `a` I want to randomly select 5 row if `a` has more than rows, else I would like to return `a` as it is.

```
a <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=1:10)
a[if(nrow(a) > 5) sample(nrow(a), 5) else 1:nrow(a), ]
```

I tried to remove the `else` clause (which didn't work) or at least omit `1:nrow(a)` in the else clause and just return 'something' so that all rows are selected (something like `a[ , ]` if `nrow(a) <= 5`). What would I have to return? I tried `NA` and `NULL` both did not work. Is there way to achieve this?

Comment: Try `if(nrow(a) > 5) a[sample(nrow(a),  5),] else a`

Comment: Thanks for your your suggestion, I guess what I am really wondering is, what do I have to return in the `else` that would be equal to 'nothing' before the comma in `a[,]. Maybe this is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can do it like this:

```
if(nrow(a)>5) {a[sample(nrow(a),5),]} else(a)
```

or like this:

```
a[if(nrow(a)>5) {sample(nrow(a),5)} else TRUE,]
```

The problem with your attempts is with the arguments you pass to sample(), you left out a comma.  The 'blank' syntax is shorthand. `TRUE` or `1:nrow(a)` achieves your objective.

Comment: Passing TRUE acts like a blank, sort of.